# Got a "The project type is not supported by this installation" when converting MVC2 application to VS2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I just installed Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 on my hard drive. I also reinstalled MVC Beta 2.

I opened then my solution in VS2010 and I got the error message "The project type is not supported by this installation". I don't really understand since, first I upgraded from MVC1 to MVC2 in Visual Studio 2008 and today I tried to convert it to 2010.

Any idea where would be the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS2010 ships with ASP.NET MVC 2 Preview 2. ASP.NET MVC 2 Beta is [not supported on VS2010](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/17/asp.net-mvc-2-beta-released.aspx).

Comment: I guess that answers the question now... I'll have to wait a few months =)